# Is there any product similar with AFTR?

Tags: networking, protocols, ipv6

AFTR is short for "Address Family Transition Router", a stand-alone, user mode application that implements a Dual-stack lite in ISC family.

Is there any other products implements a Dual-stack lite similar with AFTR? I want to learn it by comparing it with other products, and evaluate the performance of it.

Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague has tested [A10](http://ipv6ws.arkko.com/presentations/DSLite_Implementation_Experiences.pdf) with AFTR functionality, and I know that certain [Brocade](http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/white_papers/GA-WP-1574-00.pdf) products can also do AFTR.